# Second choice font in HTML

Tags: html, font-size, font-family

This might be slightly basic. Sorry for that but I was wondering if it is possible that the second choice font we specify in HTML (using font/font-family) can be of a different font-size.

Eg. Use Lucida Grande, size 13 or Arial, size 14 if that wasn't found

Comment: This source claims it's not possible in CSS: http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3446533.htm

Hopefully there is a work around someone has thought of.